# Cadastro dinâmico de dados em 2 tabelas

Tags: banco-de-dados, query, tabela-banco-de-dados

Boa tarde pessoal.

Tenho a seguinte situação:

Em um modulo de cadastro de veiculo preciso cadastrar dinamicamente e de uma só vez um veiculo seguido de todos seus modelos e grupo, sendo que um veiculo pode ter N modelos e estar cadastrado em N grupos, qual o melhor caminho para eu efetuar tal cadastro?

Ou seja, o usuário entra no modulo cadastro de veiculo e clica em CADASTRAR VEICULO então abre uma tela de cadastro e dentro deste cadastro ele informa o nome do veiculo e depois na mesma tela clica em adicionar modelo, e cadastra o modelo, foto deste modelo e insere este modelo dentro de um determinado grupo, então ele clica em ok ao lado e estes dados fica ali em stand by(ainda não foi cadastrado no bd) então após isto o usuário tem a opção de clicar novamente em cadastrar modelo e cadastrar outro modelo com outras fotos e em outro grupo e depois clica em ok e estes dados também fica em stand by.

Agora vem a parte difícil, abaixo deste form tem um botão cadastrar, quando eu clicar ali vai cadastrar o veiculo_id, veiculo_title e veiculo_name na tabela VEICULO e o veiculo_modelo, veiculo_cover, veiculo_grupo na tabela VEICULO_MODELO.

A pergunta é, qual a melhor forma para eu realizar isto? Consigo gravar simultaneamente os dados de 1 ÚNICO FORM em 2 TABELAS NO BD? Lembrando que dentro deste FORM pode existir 1 ou mais array de modelo, ou seja, se eu cadastrar um veiculo e dentro do cadastro mais 2 modelos então sera gravado os dados de veiculo na tabela veiculo e 2 registros de modelos com id diferentes na tabela veiculo_modelo

Answer (score 0):

Vai armazenando em uma tabela auxiliar quando ele finalizar os cadastros ai passa da tabela auxiliar para a principal ou armazena todos os dados em sessão inserindo assim na tabela quando terminar os cadastros

Comment: Weidson, mas se eu armazenar na sessão no final das contas terei que pegar estes dados armazenados e dividi-los enviando cada input para sua devida tabela...tem algum artigo ou alguma tag para me ajudar a pesquisar sobre como faço isto?

Answer (score 0):

Herman,

Em bancos relacionais você não consegue inserir em mais de uma tabela ao mesmo tempo. O que você precisa fazer é realizar os seus inserts utilizando uma transação afinal de contas a transação vai evitar inconsistências na caso caso ocorra algum erro.

Digamos que você vai inserir o carro GOL e o mesmo terá 3 modelos [a, b, c]. Você irá iniciar uma transação-> inserir o carro gol -> inserir os modelos -> fechar a transação. Ah mas se ocorrer um erro na gravação do modelo B? Tranquilo, o banco irá desfazer todas as alterações relacionadas a essa transação em questão.

```
BEGIN TRAN T1;
INSERT table1 ...;
SELECT table1 ...;
INSERT table2 ...;

COMMIT TRAN T1;
```

[Fonte](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/224/sql-server/transacoes-no-sql-server?trace=1519021197&source=single)

Comment: Opa Èrik, vou dar uma lida no artigo que você indicou...e depois quando eu tiver pontos de reputação suficientes volto aqui para marcar sua resposta como positiva.